# Как сделать в цикле исключение, продолжение работы скрипта?

Tags: python, list, for, try

подскажите , как сделать в цикле исключения.
Пример:

```
user_json = json.loads(req.text)

for acc in user_json['result']['per']:
        try:
            if user_json['result']['per'] is not None:
                        account.append(str(acc['name']))
            else:
                        account.append("mail.ru")
        except:
            account.append("mail.ru")
```

Такие решения не работаю, так как если в результате запросы в json нет значения result, скрипт падает

```
    for acc in user_json['result']['per']:
KeyError: 'result'
```

, а мне надо что бы если даже значения не было, он добавил значение по умолчанию в данном случае mail.ru

p.s. иногда в итерациях не приходят значениях , те что в result, их нет, так вот на этом моменте скрипт падает, а мне надо что бы итерации дальше продолжались

Comment: Ну вынесите `try:` ещё выше. А вообще проще проверять `if 'result' in user_json:`

Comment: так тоже не будет работать, если придет ошибка , то цикл закончится exceptom

Comment: Вы как-то чётче распишите ТЗ, сейчас не очень понятно что в каком случае должно быть )

Comment: я думал по коду все понятно и ошибки, иногда в итерациях не приходят значениях , их нет, так вот на этом моменте скрипт падает, а мне надо что бы итерации дальше продолжались

Comment: Это понятно, непонятно, зачем при любых ошибках добавлять в список `account.append("mail.ru")`, сколько ошибок - столько и добавлений. Как-то это странно.

Comment: @CrazyElf , мне надо значение по умолчанию добавлять если вышел пустой item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одну строчку:

```
account = [acc.get('name', "mail.ru") for acc in (user_json['result']['per'] if 'result' in user_json and 'per' in user_json['result'] else [{}])]
```

Comment: Объяснение не помешает (*читаю из "сообщений низкого качества"*).

Answer (score 0):

может вот такой способ поможет?

```
user_json = {'result': {'per': [{}, {'name': 'test'}]}}

account = []

try:
    for acc in user_json['result']['per']:
        try:
            account.append(acc['name'])
        except:
            account.append("mail.ru")
except:
    account.append("mail.ru")

print(account)
```

мне кажется вы `try..except` просто некорректно расставили

Comment: так если мы поставим трай выше, и встретится итерация где нет result, цикл же exceptom закончится, или я не прав?

Comment: @user3119496 О каких итерациях в таком случае может идти речь, если `result` вообще отсутствует?